# Node.js nvm exit status 145: The directory is not empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-10, nvm

I have Node.js version 14.18.1 installed and I want to update to 16.10.0 for compatibility for a project. To upgrade I have installed the latest version of nvm (1.1.8) and did `nvm install 16.10.0`. And then `nvm use 16.10.0` and got the error: `exit status 145: The directory is not empty.` I tried looking this up, but couldn't find anyone on the internet encountering the same issue.

I have also tried adding the path at `C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Roaming\nvm\settings.txt` to my system environment path, but that didn't work either. Does anyone have an idea as to what might work? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313372/nvm-for-windows-not-working

Comment: Try this suggestion of deleting the folder for windows.

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/674#issuecomment-956574752

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved by:

Delete all contents of folder path: `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

and try to run `nvm use 16.10.0` again.

Comment: worked for me as well, the previous version of the node wasn't properly deleted by just uninstalling